# How to print roman numerals greater than 3,999?

Tags: format, common-lisp, roman-numerals

I want to print several numbers as roman numerals but

```
(format t "~@R~%" 4000)
```

leads to the following error in SBCL 1.3.20 and a similar one using ccl:

```
Number too large to print in Roman numerals: 4,000
   [Condition of type SIMPLE-ERROR]

Restarts:
 0: [RETRY] Retry SLIME REPL evaluation request.
 1: [*ABORT] Return to SLIME's top level.
 2: [ABORT] abort thread (#<THREAD "new-repl-thread" RUNNING {100503D2B3}>)
```

I did not find any information about this limit in the [Hyperspec](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/22_cba.htm) and wasn't aware that romans had only numbers unto 3,999.

Is there a ready-to-use solution to print numbers greater than 3,999 as roman numerals?

Comment: Actually this is not a limitation of Common Lisp, but something inherent to roman numerals. For numbers over 3999, Romans added a line over a number to multiply it by 1000.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There was no consensus among the Romans on [large number representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_numerals#Large_numbers). The CL implementors demurred on resolving the controversy, especially since both approaches used by the Romans ("apostrophus" and "vinculum") are unsuitable for representation in ASCII on a TTY.

PS. `3.999` can be approximated by `IV` ;-)

Comment: I edited the number formatting to the english standard ;-)